# JQUERY FIND:FIRST not finding the first Paragraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, find

Goal, is to extract the content for the CKEDITOR Text Editor, and then only obtain the FIRST paragraph. For some reason the bellow isn't working... Ideas?

Given the following JavaScript:

```
var newTitle = CKEDITOR.instances.meeting_notes.getData(); 
newTitle = $(newTitle).find("p:first").text();
```

Comment: does newTitle contain a string or a reference to an element?

Comment: Yes it does, good question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `find()` searches the descendants and your paragraph must be at the top level of the HTML you're searching.

For example:

```
alert($("<p id='one'>one</p><p id='two'>two</p>").find("p:first").attr("id"));
```

returns "undefined" whereas:

```
alert($("<p id='one'>one</p><p id='two'>two</p>").filter("p:first").attr("id"));
```

will output "one".

So you could use `filter()` if you know it's at the top level (possibly falling back to `find()`). Alternatively you could wrap the whole lot up in a dummy element:

```
alert($("<div>" + html + "</div>").find("p:first").text());
```

**Edit:** My advice? Use:

```
newtitle = $(newtitle).filter("p:first").text();
```

Comment: Interesting, any suggestions on how I can extract the first paragraph then?

Comment: This is interesting, but the FILTER("P") is returning all the paragraphs and what I'm trying to do is just get the first paragraph. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm lost :) can you show me the line of code your suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if works for you, but just try putting a space before  **:first**, 
for some reasons i can't explain this works as far my experience is concerned:

The new selector for find would now be, find("**p: first**")

```
var newTitle = CKEDITOR.instances.meeting_notes.getData(); 
newTitle = $(newTitle).find("p :first").text();
```

BTW can you post some sample values of the newTitle, just curious of what it looks like!

Comment: That doesn't work since newTitle is an object and not a div. hmmm

Comment: can give us the structure of the object? is it a DOM object or just a JSON object.

Comment: From the CKEDITOR API: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html


{String} getData()
Since: 3.0
Gets the editor data. The data will be in raw format. It is the same data that is posted by the editor.
Defined in: core/editor.js.

Comment: if so,  newTitle = $(newTitle).filter("p :first").text();

Comment: if not, newTitle = $(newTitle).filter("p")[0].text();

Comment: or newTitle = $$( (newTitle).filter("p").get(0) ).text();

Answer (score 0):

This is completely untested, but assuming that what getData returns is a string of HTML, try this:

```
newTitle=$("<div>").html(newTitle).find("p:first").text();
```